# Regular Expression confusing

Tags: php, regex

If I have string like this `"location":"Denton TX"` (including the double quotes) 
I'd like to get just `Denton TX`. How can I write regular expression for that thing?

I tried

```
function getInfo($info,$content){
    echo 'getting INFO';
    preg_match_all("\.".$info."\.:\"[^\"]*(.*?)\.,",$content,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    print_r($matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

and I put 'location' into `$info` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get any errors, such as something about needing [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)?

Comment: No didn't get any error T___T

Comment: Second the lack of delimiters as the issue. Also, http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: How can I fix my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple get every character between quotes. You was too close.

```
"\.".$info."\.:\"([^\"]*)\"
```

Comment: It still doesn't work T__T  Why not?

function getInfo($info,$content){
    echo 'getting INFO';
    preg_match_all("\"".$info."\":\"([^\"]*)\"",$content,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    print_r($matches);
    return $matches[0];

}

print_r doesn't return any thing to me

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this:

```
"\"".$info."\":\"([^\"]+)\""
```

I'm not sure why you wrote this particular bit, but the main problem in your regex is the `[^\"]*`, which is too greedy and will consume everything, and leave `(.*?)` empty (well, unless is starts with a double quote, I guess). I also don't really understand why you what a comma in the end, but maybe your example wasn't descrptive... In any case, the regex I provided should match your example, provided `$info` contains the string `location`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (?<=:")(.*)(?=")

I use a similar one to remove element tags from an XML response in an Android app. Good luck

Comment: Actually, this would be best: (?<="location":")(.*)(?=")

http://regexr.com?34bsi